# how to using SQL INSERT INTO SELECT with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How to use the SQL insert into select in CodeIgniter.

Model...

```
public function history($book_id)
{


$query = $this->db->query('INSERT orders (book_id, title)
                       SELECT book_id, book_title
                       FROM books
                       WHERE book_id = \'$book_id\'');

  return true;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of get all books from `books` table then INSERT order according to your `$book_id`

**Example:**

```
public function history($book_id)
{
    $this->db->select('book_id, book_title');
    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->where('book_id', $book_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) // if result found
    {
        $row = $query->result_array(); // get result in an array format
        $data = array();
        foreach($row as $values){
            $data = array(
                'book_id' => $values['book_id'],
                'title' => $values['book_title']
            );
            $this->db->insert('orders', $data); // insert in order table
        }
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @tianjinchen: glad to help u dont forgot to accept the answer this will help to future visitor